# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET Quando faço upload de imagem grande no NodeJS

Tags: node.js, file-upload

Bom dia,
Estou com um problema quando tento enviar imagem grande com node, uso formidable

app.post('/upload/image', (req, res, next) => {
   var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
   form.multiples = true;

form.on('fileBegin', (field, file) => {
     var filename = crypto.createHash('md5').update(file.name).digest("hex") + ".png";
     file.path = './public/uploads/' + filename;
     req.session.linkImage = "/uploads/" + filename;

```
 res.end('uploaded');
```

});

form.on('error', (err) => {
     console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
   });

form.on('end', (fields, file) => {

```
 res.end('success');
```

});

form.parse(req);
  });

Poderia me ajudar a resolver esse problema?

Comment: Esse daqui funciona no express https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-formidable

Comment: Para o express é um especifico? Vou utilizar esse e testar